# zip file error in reading in an https url

Tags: r

I'm attempting to learn how to read in an access/zip file that has an https url into R.  This is part of a larger mapping learning project I'm undertaking to branch out my R skills found [HERE](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/23324-An-R-learning-project-%28feel-free-to-learn-with-me%29?p=76655&viewfull=1#post76655) *(I will link this post back there as well)*.

**This was the plan but I get an error from the getURL and I'm not sure why:**

```
require(RCurl)
NYSdemo <- getURL("https://reportcards.nysed.gov/zip/SRC2010.zip")
temp <- tempfile()
download.file(NYSdemo, temp)
data <- read.table(unz(temp, "a1.dat"))
unlink(temp)
```

**ERROR:**

```
> NYSdemo <- getURL("https://reportcards.nysed.gov/zip/SRC2010.zip")
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Like I said this is a learning project so many of the techniques I'm using here I am not at all familiar with.

The actual zip file I'm trying to download is [HERE](https://reportcards.nysed.gov/view.php?county=yes&year=2010)

Maybe this isn't actually a programming problem but something wrong with the URL that doesn't enable getURL to be used on it.

Thank you in advance for your ideas and help.

***EDIT: I attempted the ssl.verifypeer but get another error***

```
> NYSdemo <- getURL("https://reportcards.nysed.gov/zip/SRC2010.zip",
+ ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
Error in curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding) : 
  embedded nul in string: 'PK\003\004\024\0\0\0\b\0i[j>¶U#]tó\036\005\0 ÷- {And it continues}
>
```

***EDIT 2: Per Vincent's Suggestions***

```
> NYSdemo <- getURL("http://reportcards.nysed.gov/zip/SRC2010.zip")
> download.file(NYSdemo, temp)
Error in download.file(NYSdemo, temp) : unsupported URL scheme
> 
> NYSdemo <- getBinaryURL("https://reportcards.nysed.gov/zip/SRC2010.zip")
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
> 
> url.exists("https://reportcards.nysed.gov/zip/SRC2010.zip")
[1] FALSE   #not sure why this is because it works to type into url bar of browser
```

This information is leading me to believe that the problem is something strange about the zip file.  Ideas?

Comment: The error message says that the identity of the website could not be verified. You can try to bypass those checks by replacing `https`by `http` (but the connection becomes unsecure). You might also need to replace `getURL` with `getBinaryURL`.

Comment: @Vincent Zoonekynd  Thank you for the response.  I attempted your suggestions (see EDIT 2) but have not had luck.

Comment: Your original error is fairly easy to fix. It is the errors in your first edit that are your real problem. > Blockquote "Error in curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding) : embedded nul in string: 'PK\003\004\024\0\0\0\b\0i[j>¶U#]tó\036\005\0 ÷- {And it continues}" This is the area that needs to be fixed but I am not sure how to do it. Others will though I am sure.

Comment: If you no longer have an error message after `getURL`, it worked, and the contents of the file is in the `NYSdemo` variable. `download.file` does the same thing as `getURL` (so you do not need both), and expects a URL as argument: `download.file("http://...")`.

Comment: @Vincent I don't think it worked because the contents of NYSdemo after getURL gives: `[1] "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>302 Found</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Found</h1>\n<p>The document has moved <a href=\"https://reportcards.nysed.gov/zip/SRC2010.zip\">here</a>.</p>\n</body></html>\n"` I don't think I want this.

Comment: Is there a way to forgo the getURL and use just download.file?

Comment: `download.file` does not work with https. The following may work: `NYSdemo <- getBinaryURL("https://reportcards.nysed.gov/zip/SRC2010.zip",  ssl.verifypeer = FALSE); write(NYSdemo, file = temp)`.

Comment: You could scrape the webpage and search for "something.zip" using regular expressions and download that.

Comment: @ Vincent Zoonekynd I can down load the binary as you suggest.  It's a huge file.  What can I do with that?  How do I turn it into a data base file I can use?

Comment: I think you get "embedded nul in string" because R tries to convert the file from raw to ascii using rawToChar. At least you get the same error message if you first use getBinaryURL (which works fine) and then try to put the result into 'rawToChar()'. What actually worked in my case was to write the binary file to file, and then read it using data.table (which handles zip files). See Bryan Goodrich's answer below and my comment to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you didn't believe me over at TS, I tested my solution with the help of whoever it was that gave the ssl.verify idea.

```
bin <- getBinaryURL("https://reportcards.nysed.gov/zip/SRC2010.zip",
                    ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)
con <- file("schools.zip", open = "wb")
writeBin(bin, con)
close(con)
```

Since the file is big, it took me awhile to download the binary, but it wrote it *real* fast. Make sure to close the connection so you can open your ZIP file afterwards. I was able to open both the PDF and the Access database.