# Using system with windows

Tags: r

I have the following string I'm trying to pass to `system` on a Win 7 machine.  It should be creating the `.git` directory in a repo but using `system` it does not (though a similar approach does work on a Linux box so this is a Windows specific problem).

```
system( "cd C:/Users/trinker/Desktop/foo2 && \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\git.exe\" init" )
```

`C:/Users/trinker/Desktop/foo2` is the location of a repo. `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\git.exe` is the location of git on my system.

When I run the above nothing happens.  No message, nadda.  But is I run `cat` on the string and paste it directly into the command line it runs, gives the following message and creates `.git` in the appropriate place.

**So running...**

```
cat("cd C:/Users/trinker/Desktop/foo2 && \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\git.exe\" init")
```

**Pasting this into the command line...**

```
cd C:/Users/trinker/Desktop/foo2 && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" init
```

**Gives...**

```
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/trinker/Desktop/foo2/.git/
```

**...Which is good**

So I can do it outside of R with the same string but not within R.  What do I need to do to the first string where I use `system` to make it run as if though I `cat` and pasted into the command line?  An answer is great but I'd like to know what's going on here so I can address similar circumstances in the future with accessing the Windows command line with `system`.

Comment: What happens if you pass your string through `shQuote` first?

Comment: I think you're on to the correct response but: `system(shQuote("cd C:/Users/trinker/Desktop/foo2 && \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\git.exe\" init"))` gives the same result of nothing.

Comment: Maybe `shQuote` is struggling to handle the escaped quotation marks?

Comment: I tried removing that as well.  I also tried running `shQuote` on just the git location and pasting together into `system` with the same result.

Comment: Try `system( 'cd C:/Users/trinker/Desktop/foo2 && \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\git.exe\" init' )`

Comment: Any particular reason you're using forward slashes for the call to cd and backslashes for git?

Comment: @Dason no.  No reason.

Comment: This is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042418/send-to-github-via-curl-command-line-windows

Comment: on windows you need to use `shell` to run this command, not `system`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try - at least for me using `system("cd blah blah && blah blah", intern = TRUE)` gave `Error in system(cmd, intern = T) : 'cd' not found` so using cd is out - luckily the working directory is used so you can just change the working directory in R instead of in a system call.

```
wd <- getwd()
setwd("C:/Users/trinker/Desktop/foo2")
cmd <- '"C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe" init'
system(cmd, intern = T)
setwd(wd)
```

The intern parameter isn't necessary but it can help for debugging.

I'm just thankful I typically run on Linux ;)

Comment: Boom Perfect that does it.

Answer (score 5):

On windows use `shell`. This works just fine for me...

```
shell( "cd C:/Data/foo2 && \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\git.exe\" init" )
#CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
#UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
#Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Data/foo2/.git/
```

Comment: Seems like `shell` is a much nicer approach on windows.  I wonder if git.exe would be on the path via shell (of course this would depend on the system though)

Comment: @Simon, do you think you could help with this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32679330/how-to-get-the-cpu-temperature-info-using-r